# what does mysql_query() wordpress function return?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

So i need to create custom queries in my wordpress site.  I stumbled upon this function:

```
mysql_query()
```

that is supposedly supported in wordpress.  I could not find any developer documentation on it and not sure what type of return value it returns or how to process it etc...also is there a better way to write custom sql queries in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to write custom queries in Wordpress, you should use the [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) global object.

Also, `mysql_query` is a deprecated PHP function...

Comment: i c.  so what is the general method/function for custom query in wordpress?  can you provide example?  I don't want to rely on wpdb->insert for instance, but rather something like "wpdb->query($sql)"